# Rename a set of image files using the names with two or more words separated by commas that are in a txt file

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

The text file contains these names:

```
Achilles Reef , Island Emerald Falcon , Octopus Noelle Phoenix , Scribe Magenta Phoenix
```

I'd like the images in the folder to look like this (regardless of their original name i.e. `random.jpg`):

```
Achilles Reef.jpg
Island Emerald Falcon.jpg
Octopus Noelle Phoenix.jpg
Scribe Magenta Phoenix.jpg
```

Comment: What's the actual real-life purpose of this exercise? How are the input files identified - is it just the first 4 files in the folder in alphabetical order? What did you already try?

Comment: ... And more importantly, the image files in your directory seem to already reflect the names in your file (so already renamed?) ... Are we messing something? ... Please also see my edit to your question and change it if it doesn't reflect your intention.

Comment: @Raffa I think maybe the second part is the "intended" output, but we don't know since it isn't explained.

Comment: the images are used by a mod in a game for a killfeed that applies the images to a bot as a avatar. when I wipe the server it wipes the bots and they randomly are assigned new names. but the images are named from the previous bots, so I have to manually change their names of the images to the new bot names and it does not matter what image goes to what bot names. usually I have up to 60 bots and images in the folder. I just copied the new bot names to a file hoping to use that to rename all the images files using the file I copied the names into.

Comment: Your post lacks of a question... What are the current names of the files? What did you already try and didn't work?

Comment: my current names are random names from bots from before last wipe Achilles Reef.jpg
Island Emerald Falcon.jpg
Octopus Noelle Phoenix.jpg
Scribe Magenta Phoenix.jpg and etc. my new names I want to replace these old names with. I tried using this from what I searched on these forums. '@echo off
for /F "delims=" %%a in (imagefile.txt) do (
   for /f %%i in ('dir /b /o:n *.jpg') do echo ren "%%i" "%%a[%%~ni]%%~xi"
)'

Comment: @upperking please stop replying in comments - instead [edit] your question so that it contains all the necessary information

Comment: It wont let me edit after 5 minutes. I tried running bot below and errors C:\Users\Main Office\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder (7)>    (( "$i" < "${#n[@]}" )) && [ -f "$f" ] && mv -nv -- "$f" "${n[$i]}.jpg"
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Users\Main Office\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder (7)>    ((i++))
'i++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: OK so clearly you are using Windows not Ubuntu here

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the names in a separate file ... Store them as array elements in the very Bash script file that will rename the files like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

n=(
"Achilles Reef"
"Island Emerald Falcon"
"Octopus Noelle Phoenix"
"Scribe Magenta Phoenix"
)

i=0

for f in *.jpg
  do 
    (( "$i" < "${#n[@]}" )) && [ -f "$f" ] && mv -nv -- "$f" "${n[$i]}.jpg"
    ((i++))
  done
```

However, if you must read names from a file, then you can define the array by passing parsed names as lines to `readarray` instead like so:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

readarray -t n < <(awk -F' , ' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i}' /path/to/file.txt)

i=0

for f in *.jpg
  do 
    (( "$i" < "${#n[@]}" )) && [ -f "$f" ] && mv -nv -- "$f" "${n[$i]}.jpg"
    ((i++))
  done
```

**notice** that you must be accurate with the field separator i.e. `-F' , '` will consider  `,`  that is one space   then comma `,` then another single space   altogether as a field separator.

See this demonstration:

```
$ touch {1..4}.jpg
ubuntu@localhost:~/test$ LC_ALL=en_US ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   0 Jan  8 18:50 1.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   0 Jan  8 18:50 2.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   0 Jan  8 18:50 3.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   0 Jan  8 18:50 4.jpg
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 231 Jan  8 18:49 script.bash
ubuntu@localhost:~/test$ cat script.bash 
#!/bin/bash

n=(
"Achilles Reef"
"Island Emerald Falcon"
"Octopus Noelle Phoenix"
"Scribe Magenta Phoenix"
)

i=0

for f in *.jpg
  do 
    (( "$i" < "${#n[@]}" )) && [ -f "$f" ] && mv -nv -- "$f" "${n[$i]}.jpg"
    ((i++))
  done
ubuntu@localhost:~/test$ bash script.bash
renamed '1.jpg' -> 'Achilles Reef.jpg'
renamed '2.jpg' -> 'Island Emerald Falcon.jpg'
renamed '3.jpg' -> 'Octopus Noelle Phoenix.jpg'
renamed '4.jpg' -> 'Scribe Magenta Phoenix.jpg'
ubuntu@localhost:~/test$ LC_ALL=en_US ls -l
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   0 Jan  8 18:50 'Achilles Reef.jpg'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   0 Jan  8 18:50 'Island Emerald Falcon.jpg'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   0 Jan  8 18:50 'Octopus Noelle Phoenix.jpg'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu   0 Jan  8 18:50 'Scribe Magenta Phoenix.jpg'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 231 Jan  8 18:49  script.bash
```

Of course you can make the script file executable with `chmod +x script.bash` and then run it with the path either absolute like `/full/path/to/script.bash` or relative like `./script.bash` or you can copy it to a directory in your search path and run it as a command like `script.bash` ... You can also either run it from within the directory containing those image files or specify the full path to that directory in the head of the `for` loop like `for f in /full/path/to/directory/*.jpg` and then you can run the script from anywhere in the filesystem hierarchy.